# defrecord with optional keys

Tags: clojure

I am a total newbie to clojure and trying to follow some tutorials basically. I have a question about `defrecord`s.

Here is the thing that I am trying to do :

```
(defrecord somemap [key1 key2 key3 key4])

(defn give-me-map [m1 m2]
  (somemap. m1 m2))
```

On the code above, i would like to have `key3` and `key4` as optional, so that i wont need to give values to them each time a create a `somemap` object.

there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580606/create-optional-fields-on-clojure-record), but it does the reverse of what i am trying to do here.

So the is it possible to define `defrecord` with optional fields?

Comment: If you are a total newbie to clojure, you might wanna skip defrecord and it's cousins for now. You can write quite a bit of useful code without them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you use `(defrecord T [...])`, two factory functions are created: `->T` and `map->T`.

The first uses the positional parameters as keys. The second applies an arbitrary map to the record.

You can keep `key3` and `key4` in the constructor and use `map->somemap`.

```
(defrecord somemap [key1 key2 key3 key4])

(defn give-me-map
  [key1 key2]
  (map->somemap {:key1 key1 :key2 key2}))
```

Answer (score 6):

Since records in Clojure implement the map interface, all fields except for the ones specified in the constructor are optional.

So, declaring your record with only `key1` and `key2` is correct: only `key1` and `key2` will be required in the constructor, but you can easily set `key3` or `key4` (or any other key, for that matter) by associng a value to them onto the record like any other map.

Comment: My understanding of records is that all keys are optional when using the map-> constructor.
See for instance:
```
(defrecord Bar [a b c])
(def r (map->Bar {:c 30})) ;; #my-ns.Bar{:a nil, :b nil, :c 30}```